# GVIM crashes when running python

Tags: python, vim, crash

I cannot use python in GVIM. When I type:
`:python print 1` it just closes GVIM without any message. I triend to run it with `-V90logfile` but I couldn't find any information about the crash.

GVIM is compiled with python (`:version` shows `+python/dyn +python3/dyn`).

GVIM version: 7.3.46 (32 bit with OLE).
Python version: 2.7.3

Initially GVIM couldn't find python27.dll so I edited `$MYVIMRC` and added:

`let $Path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Python27;".$Path`

Both GVIM and Python have been installed using corporate standards - not manually via installers. Asking here as IT were not able to help me and redirected to external support.

I could reproduce the error on my personal computer, where I copied both GVIM & PYTHON without installing them. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally solved the problem.

It turned out that Python uses `PYTHONPATH` variable to resolve the PYTHON folder (used to load python libraries and so on). Here is the default value for Python 2.7:

`C:\Python27\Lib;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk`

The variable can be set using one of the following:

### 1. Windows registry

Set the default value of `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Python\PythonCore\2.7\PythonPath` key

### 2. Environment variable

Create environment variable `PYTHONPATH` and set the value (same as you edit global `PATH`)

### 3. _vimrc file

This is the most portable way. Edit your _vimrc (i.e. open vim and enter `:e $MYVIMRC` command) and set the variable:

`let $PYTHONPATH = "C:\\Python27\\Lib;C:\\Python27\\DLLs;C:\\Python27\\Lib\\lib-tk"`

Comment: Great! this is the last piece to get my gvim to run ConqueTerm!

Comment: For me setting `PYTHONPATH` to `C:\\Python\\lib` worked for python 3.6.4 and latest vim.

Comment: Setting `PYTHONPATH` globally proved to be a bad idea since it breaks old python2.7 scripts (running without virtualenv). `let $PYTHONPATH="C:\\Python\\lib"` works better.

Answer (score 1):

Vim seems finicky about the Python DLL version. 2.7.11 (the current one, as I write this) doesn't work. I installed 2.7.9 per another SO answer on a similar topic and it worked fine.

Note that the Python installer puts the DLLs into `C:\Windows\system32` (or similar depending on language), this should be in your path automatically but in my case I just wanted Python-in-Vim to work regardless of what I had installed so I copied the 2.7.9 DLLs into the Vim installation directory.

Perhaps the Python [virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) package would help here too but I have only just learned of it and not tried it.